# WANTED: xslt hack to get rid of duplicates in output

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach

In the following xml-data, several items have different IDs. For example, item "apfel" has several IDs instead of always the same one.

```
<lieferungen>
    <artikel id="3526">
        <name>apfel</name>
        <lieferant>Fa. Krause</lieferant>
        <preis stueckpreis="true">8.97</preis>
    </artikel>
    <artikel id="7866">
        <name>Kirschen</name>
        <preis stueckpreis="false">10.45</preis>
        <lieferant>Fa. Helbig</lieferant>
    </artikel>
    <artikel id="3526">
        <preis stueckpreis="true">12.67</preis>
        <lieferant>Fa. Liebig</lieferant>
        <name>apfel</name>
    </artikel>
    <artikel id="7866">
        <preis stueckpreis="false">17.67</preis>
        <name>Kirschen</name>
        <lieferant>Fa. Krause</lieferant>
    </artikel>
    <artikel id="3627">
        <name>apfel</name>
        <lieferant>Fa. Mertes</lieferant>
        <preis stueckpreis="true">9.54</preis>
    </artikel>
    <artikel id="7866">
        <name>Kirschen</name>
        <lieferant>Fa. Hoeller</lieferant>
        <preis stueckpreis="false">16.45</preis>
    </artikel>
    <artikel id="7868">
        <preis>3.20</preis>
        <name>Kohl</name>
        <lieferant>Fa. Hoeller</lieferant>
    </artikel>
    <artikel id="7866">
        <name>Kirschen</name>
        <lieferant>Fa. Richard</lieferant>
        <preis stueckpreis="false">12.45</preis>
    </artikel>
    <artikel id="3245">
        <preis stueckpreis="false">15.67</preis>
        <name>Bananen</name>
        <lieferant>Fa. Hoeller</lieferant>
    </artikel>
    <artikel id="6745">
        <name>Kohl</name>
        <lieferant>Fa. Reinhardt</lieferant>
        <preis stueckpreis="false">3.10</preis>
    </artikel>
    <artikel id="7789">
        <name>Ananas</name>
        <preis stueckpreis="true">8.60</preis>
        <lieferant>Fa. Richard</lieferant>
    </artikel>
</lieferungen>
```

I want to summarise the inconsistencies in the following way:

[image]

To this end I wrote the following xslt-code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"    
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="lieferungen">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>
                    <xsl:text>Inkonsistenzen</xsl:text>
                </title>
            </head>
            <body bgcolor="#ffffff">
                <h1>
                    <xsl:text>Inkonsistenzen</xsl:text>
                </h1>
                <hr/>
                <p>
                    <xsl:text>Die Datei enthält folgende Inkonsistenzen: 
                </xsl:text>
                </p>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                <hr/>

            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="artikel">
        <xsl:variable name="this_name" select="name/text()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="this_id" select="@id"/>
        <xsl:variable name="this_prod" select="lieferant/text()"/>

        <xsl:for-each select="//artikel">
            <xsl:if test="name/text() = $this_name">
                <xsl:if test="not(@id = $this_id)">
                    <p>
                        <xsl:text>Inkonsistenz: Name1=</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$this_name"/>
                        <xsl:text>; Lieferant1=</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$this_prod"/>
                        <xsl:text>; ID1=</xsl:text>
                        <u>
                            <b>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$this_id"/>
                            </b>
                        </u>
                        <xsl:text> ; Name2=</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="name/text()"/>
                        <xsl:text>; Lieferant2=</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="lieferant/text()"/>
                        <xsl:text>; ID2=</xsl:text>
                        <u>
                            <b>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
                            </b>
                        </u>
                    </p>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output of this is the following:

```
Inkonsistenzen


   Die Datei enthält folgende Inkonsistenzen:
   Inkonsistenz: Name1=apfel; Lieferant1=Fa. Krause; ID1=3526 ; Name2=apfel;    
   Lieferant2=Fa. Mertes; ID2=3627
   Inkonsistenz: Name1=apfel; Lieferant1=Fa. Liebig; ID1=3526 ; Name2=apfel; 
   Lieferant2=Fa. Mertes; ID2=3627
   Inkonsistenz: Name1=apfel; Lieferant1=Fa. Mertes; ID1=3627 ; Name2=apfel; 
   Lieferant2=Fa. Krause; ID2=3526
   Inkonsistenz: Name1=apfel; Lieferant1=Fa. Mertes; ID1=3627 ; Name2=apfel; 
   Lieferant2=Fa. Liebig; ID2=3526
   Inkonsistenz: Name1=Kohl; Lieferant1=Fa. Hoeller; ID1=7868 ; Name2=Kohl; 
   Lieferant2=Fa. Reinhardt; ID2=6745
   Inkonsistenz: Name1=Kohl; Lieferant1=Fa. Reinhardt; ID1=6745 ; Name2=Kohl; 
   Lieferant2=Fa. Hoeller; ID2=7868
```

So, the output contains exactly twice as many items as I wanted. The reason for this is that every Lieferant (supplier) is appearing both as Lieferant 1 (supplier 1) and as Lieferant 2 (supplier 2).

The code responsible for the duplication is the following:

```
         <xsl:for-each select="//artikel">
            <xsl:if test="name/text() = $this_name">
                <xsl:if test="not(@id = $this_id)">
                    <p>
                        <xsl:text>Inkonsistenz: Name1=</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$this_name"/>
                        <xsl:text>; Lieferant1=</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$this_prod"/>
                        <xsl:text>; ID1=</xsl:text>
                        <u>
                            <b>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$this_id"/>
                            </b>
                        </u>
                        <xsl:text> ; Name2=</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="name/text()"/>
                        <xsl:text>; Lieferant2=</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="lieferant/text()"/>
                        <xsl:text>; ID2=</xsl:text>
                        <u>
                            <b>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
                            </b>
                        </u>
                    </p>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

I know why the duplication occurs with the current code but I do not know how to change it in order to get to the desired output.

Comment: This seems to be a *grouping* problem. If you're using XSLT 1.0, read how to best handle it here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest fix for this, is to change this line...

```
 <xsl:for-each select="//artikel">
```

To this..

```
 <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::artikel">
```

That is to say, rather than compare against all `artikels`, just compare the ones following it (because the ones before have already been considered).

Note that you can avoid some nesting, but adding the conditions in the two `xsl:if` to the `xsl:for-each` instead

```
<xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::artikel[name = $this_name][not(@id = $this_id)]">
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution!!